# Patching SharePoint Foundation 2013 any different from patching SharePoint 2013 Standard edition?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, cumulative-update

Patching SharePoint Foundation 2013 any different from patching SharePoint 2013 Standard edition?

Are there any do`s and don`ts to be taken care apart from usual process followed for patching SharePoint Standard editions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between patching of Foundation & server.

- Make sure that you pick the Foundation's bit not the server.
- Same rule applies, Test in lower farm then apply in production